# Rejecting pattern at the beginning and selecting rest of the text in string

Tags: c#, regex

How to reject pattern that appears at the beginning of the string and selecting rest afterwards.

Say my string is "pattern how's going?" Need to reject this pattern whatever it may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use string.Replace and replace the rejected pattern with nothing (that is "")
you can also use regex to get rest of text but the primary solution should be ok.
Best regard

Comment: no solution. What will happen if the pattern is part of the ending part of the string?